# Converting keys from float to int in dict in dict in list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've a dict data as below. I want to convert the float into integers. How do I go about it? I tried a few ways but to no avail.

data:

```
data =
{'ABC': {'2020-09-01': [{487.0: (0, 1), 488.0: (1, 2)}, {489.0: (0, 1), 481.0: (1, 2)}]},
'CDE': {'2020-01-01': [{484.0: (0, 1), 483.0: (1, 2)}, {482.0: (0, 1), 481.0: (1, 2)}]}}
```

I want this:

```
{'ABC': {'2020-09-01': [{487: (0, 1), 488: (1, 2)}, {489: (0, 1), 481: (1, 2)}]},
'CDE': {'2020-01-01': [{484: (0, 1), 483: (1, 2)}, {482: (0, 1), 481: (1, 2)}]}}
```

I tried this code, but I get this error "RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration":
I understand keys are immutable so I googled and found "pop" is an alternative solution

```
for i in data:
    for date in data[i]:
        for model in range(0, len(data[i][date])):
            for k, v in data[i][date][model].items():
                data[i][date][model][int(k)] = data[i][date][model].pop(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are tying to modify the dictionary while iterating over the same in:

```
for k, v in data[i][date][model].items():
      data[i][date][model][int(k)] = data[i][date][model].pop(k)
```

You could consider using list comprehension instead:

```
for k_l1, v_l1 in data.items(): #iterate first level of dict
    for k_l2, v_l2 in v_l1.items(): #iterate second level of dict
        data[k_l1][k_l2] = [{ int(key): val  for key, val in elt.items() } for elt in v_l2] # update the list
```

Output:

```
{'ABC': {'2020-09-01': [{487: (0, 1), 488: (1, 2)}, {489: (0, 1), 481: (1, 2)}]}, 'CDE': {'2020-01-01': [{484: (0, 1), 483: (1, 2)}, {482: (0, 1), 481: (1, 2)}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks but the output is wrong. The list should have 2 dictionaries instead of 1 @Krishna Chaurasia

Comment: But it's okay I used your idea and got the answer myself. @Krishna Chaurasia

Comment: I have updated the code, please verify now, there was a minor adjustment.